# how to set number of jobs for GNU parallel in my script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

In the following script I want to explicitly set number of concurrent jobs to run the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/parallel -j 2 --shebang-wrap /bin/bin
echo hi "$@"
```

when I run the script, I get the following error:
parallel: Error parsing of --jobs/-j/--max-proc/-P failed

any Idea on how to set number of jobs when making an existing script parallel?

Comment: I think the argument to `--shebang-wrap` should be `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

> --shebang-wrap must be set as the first option.

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/parallel --shebang-wrap -j 2 /bin/bash
echo hi "$@"
```